# Listing of lawsuits against Fox News and CNN?

Tags: united-states, reference-request, fake-news

Is there a source that lists lawsuits against Fox News and CNN (and perhaps other news media)?  It would be useful if the results could be limited by date range, and could exclude internal matters such as sexual harassment claims.  Basically, I want to know about suits claiming that one or the other is publishing "fake news".

The motivation for this is a discussion with a person who claims CNN gets sued for "fake news", but Fox doesn't.  Now I know, just from reading the news, that this isn't so, but I don't know relative numbers.  I've tried various searches, but only get articles relating to specific lawsuits, not any sort of overall statistics.

Comment: It's not lawsuits specifically, but some of the sites linked in answrs to my old question touch on reliability of news from both sources: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/49797/has-anyone-attempted-to-scientifically-determine-whether-msnbc-or-fox-news-is-mo

Comment: Possibly a better question for law.stackexchange.com, but even there the framing of the question has issues. Anyone can sue for anything; it doesn't mean their case has merit. That especially holds true in this era of performative litigation, where public figures file suit apparently just for the publicity. Also, in terms of suits against CNN or Fox, one of the more common current litigants is the Trump campaign, which would skew the numbers toward CNN and away from Fox.

Comment: @jeffronicus: While it's true that any number of baseless suits could be filed, you'd have to start with a listing of all lawsuits and somehow winnow out the baseless ones.  So a database with the status - dismissed, pending, judgement made, &c - would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Federal cases can be researched on [Pacer](https://pacer.uscourts.gov), the Federal Courts document database.   It is not free, but would probably be able to answer some of your questions.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems that the case locator might do what I wanted, but using it would be well beyond my financial means.

Comment: I think they only charge for documents,, not the index.